# document.write form element value. test java script function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to test a java script function the purpose of the function is to get the value of a user selected form element. Specifically a radio button. my goal is to use this function in another function to calculate a price total. But for now, I just want to make sure this function returns the value of the selected radio button.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="testForm"> 
            <legend>Calculate your square feet</legend>                
            </br>
            <label> What size plants are you starting with ? </label>
            </br>
            </br>           
            <input type="radio"  name="plantType" value="16"/>Seeds, havn't started yet</label>
            </br>
            <input type="radio"  name="plantType" value="16"/> Seedlings, less than 2ft high</label>
            </br>
            <input type="radio"  name="plantType" value="32"/> Juvenile, 2 - 4ft high</label>
            </br>
            <input type="radio"  name="plantType" value="64"/> Adult, 4ft or higher</label>
            </br>

        </form>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 




var plant_name =  new Array();
plant_name[16] = 16;
plant_name[16] = 16;
plant_name[32] = 32;
plant_name[32] = 64;



function getPlantSize() {
                var plantSize = 0;
                var theForm = document.testForm;
                var selectedPlant = theForm.plantType;
                for (var i = 0; i < plantType.length; i++)
    {
        if (plantType[i].checked)
    {
        plantSize = plant_name.[selectedPlant[i].value];
        break;
    }
        document.write (plantSize);
    }




}


    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question? There's no any functions in the posted code. What comes to [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write), it's extremely bad to use it for testing, since it wipes out all the previous code in a page when called after the page has been parsed. Use `console.log()` instead, or at least `alert()` or `document.body.innerHTML`...

Comment: You do not see function getPlantSize() ?

Comment: Outch, a poorly worded comment (again), I meant I can't see you calling any functions in your code, I'm sorry for the confusion : ). But there's no question in your post...

Comment: Do I simply call the function after the closing } or do I include an event handler in the radio button attributes, such as onClick="getPlantSize() . My bad. You are absolutely right thta i did not call the function. Newbie mistakes.

Comment: Looks like the function would find the checked radio button. However, everything will be gone after `document.write()` has been executed. Usually you need this before submitting a form, but you can also attach an `onclick` to radio buttons (`onchange` won't work with radio buttons).

Comment: Ok. Changed document.write to console.log. When I click a radio button ,I get no response.  I tried calling the function after the } tag.  Like this getPlantSize(); no success that way. Then I removed the function call and added onClick="getPlantSize()" to radio button attributes. Still no success. Any other ideas?

Comment: Some [fixes to your code](http://jsfiddle.net/SB7wa/) makes it work...

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated. I have spent many hours trying to figure this out.